# Hover effect causes floated navigation item to drop out of its containing element after making padding a percentage instead of pixels?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position, margins

I'm just beginning one of my first web design projects for a friend, and I am trying to make a responsive page. When I changed the margin of my fixed navigation link items from pixels to percentages, it causes the element to drop when hovering over any of the navigation items.
HTML

```
    <header>
    <div id="fixedLinks">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Resume</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="socialMedia">
      <a href="http://facebook.com"><img class="socialIcons" id="facebook" src="1438210007_social_facebook_box_blue.png"/></a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com"><img class="socialIcons" id="twitter" src="1438210015_social_twitter_box_blue.png"></a>
      <a href=http://linkedin.com><img class="socialIcons" id="linkedIn" src="1438210011_social_linkedin_box_blue.png"/></a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

CSS

```
 header{
  z-index: 1;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:#2F2F2F;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 1rem .1rem black;
}

#fixedLinks{
  float:left;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  font-family:EB Garamond;
  margin-left:.75%;
}

#fixedLinks a{
  color:#9B9B9B;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:1%;
  padding-right:1%;
}

#fixedLinks a:hover{
  border-left: solid 1px white;
}
```

Like I said its only when I use a 1% padding instead of 10px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not accounting for the space that is taken up by the border.

You're going from

```
Home      to      | Home
```

you need to account for this in your padding, I used this and it worked for me.

```
#fixedLinks a{
  color:#9B9B9B;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:.9%;
  padding-right:.9%;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to960pst/5/) as well.

Comment: AH of course! I was overlooking the fact that I added a border because I was going to take it out anyway. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: Actually... I'm not sure what happened, but I changed the hover effect to change the color to white, and it kicked the "contact" link down again. No border involved... Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh you added a width to the element, but why wouldn't the element naturally expand? Like it already does